# Resource does not contain a definition for Raw while migrating resources in a MAUI app and how to load them

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

While migrating a Xamarin forms app, I find my self having this Android specific code that try to load my sound resource with a resource id

```
MediaPlayer.Create(Android.App.Application.Context, Resource.Raw.beepok);
```

I see that maui is bunding everything on `Resources\Raw\**` as MauiAsset

How i can still get the resource id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem that AndroidResource still works, it seem that i was hit a build cache of sort, after clean and restarting vs the resource is available